# How to disable object lists in Openstack Swift container

Tags: cloud, openstack, openstack-swift, object-storage, ovh

We are using Openstack Object Storage (SWIFT) to store large files
When we using browser navigate to a container, it listed all objects belong in.
The document locate at: https://developer.openstack.org/api-ref/object-storage/?expanded=#show-container-details-and-list-objects
We don't want customer can browser this list file by security
How can we disable it ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Probably your container has the header "X-Container-Read" with this values:

**.r:*,.rlistings**

Where:
.r:* => public reading
.rlistings => public listing

You should remove the public listing conf, upadating the header "X-Container-Read".

Using curl, it would be something like this:

```
curl -X POST -H 'X-Auth-Token: <token-id>'  -H 'X-Container-Read: .r:*' <AdminURL>/<container>
```

Using python-swiftclient, this syntax should work:

```
swift post --read-acl .r:* container
```

Btw, just remember to set you environment variables or inform your credential on the command line to the correct use of python-swiftclient.

PS: it won't remove the reading permission, just the listing permission.

Comment: I tried this, using auth v3 but api keeps saying 204 no content-.

Comment: 204 is the expectes answer for this request.